# C++ Getting a strange output when overloading postfix increment operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I threw everything I had into a single source file and uploaded it to [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Pqn2cLPR) for easy debugging.

My problem is with the postfix increment operator.
In my output, I get this:

```
Preincrement expressions:
(-11 - 2i)
(-117 + 44i)

Postincrement expressions:
(-1.07374e+08 - 1.07374e+08i)
(-1.07374e+08 - 1.07374e+08i)

After postincrement expressions:
(-1199 - 718i)
(-922077 + 1.72176e+06i)
```

When I am expecting this:

```
Preincrement expressions:
(-11 - 2i)
(-117 + 44i)

Postincrement expressions:
(-11 - 2i)
(-117 + 44i)

After postincrement expressions:
(-1199 - 718i)
(-922077 + 1.72176e+06i)
```

I am getting a strange output for "Preincrement expressions". During debugging I can see that the values stored in the temporary object are correct until it comes time to format and output them.
 Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (without one we can't really help you).

Comment: You are returning a reference to a local variable.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39992e784db3b771

Comment: All questions on stackoverflow.com must include all pertinent information in the question itself, ***as plain text***. Dodgy links to external web sites that can stop working at any time are not acceptable.

Comment: Part of what makes post-increment operations potentially expensive is that they must return the *prior* value before the application of the operator. That nearly always involves a copy of some sort, and a return of said-same *by value*.  It's a common mistake. (Making the same mistake with `operator +`, `operator -`, is just as common).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove '&' in returning type of your postfix operator++:

```
// h
Complex operator++(Complex &a, int); //Post
// cpp
Complex operator++(Complex &a, int) //Post
{
    Complex temp(a.r, a.i);
    a.cube(temp);
    return temp;
}
```

Postfix operator should return object by value, not by reference. Otherwise, you return a reference to local variable, what is bad practice.

Comment: Doing this gives me a new error in the main. https://imgur.com/XzC0SOw.png

Comment: @Shadowdevo your `>>` operator needs to take a `const Complex&`

Comment: Even after doing this I am still getting the same incorrect values.

Comment: Scratch that! I got it working with your advice. Had to double check why it wasn't working. Forgot to remove the & before both operators. However now I've run into a new problem to do with formatting. I'll figure this out though. Thank you for the help!

Comment: For anyone who views this question with a similar issue here is the updated code (including the fix to the formatting) which is completely working as intended https://pastebin.com/5WRtd7HR